# python strptime correct format for sub seconds

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

My datetime data is like this:

```
2016-03-01 19:25:53.053404
```

I am trying to use

```
datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %HH:%MM:%SS")
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '2016-03-01 19:24:35.165425' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %HH:%MM:%SS'
```

How can I fix the format "`%Y-%m-%d %HH:%MM:%SS`" to match the datetime format that I have?

Comment: Thanks @bmcculley. I think the error python gives is changed since the other question was posted 6 years ago, so I couldn't find the other answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct format:

```
datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Breakdown:

- `%H`: Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%M`: Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%S`: Second as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%f`: Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to include two characters for hours, seconds and minutes in your format string; `%S` is "Second as a zero-padded decimal number", `%H` is "  Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.", etc. It's also worth noting that you're completely missing the symbol for microseconds (`%f`). You should add that if you want your format_string to work.

Here is a link to the [`strftime()` and `strptime()` behavior documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

[Per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) (I recommend bookmarking that link if you're planning to do any significant work with python dates and times), the correct directives for zero-padded hours, minutes, and seconds, are `%H`, `%M`, and `%S`, respectively (no doubled characters)

Further, your input strings include microseconds, so you'll need to either remove those from the inputs or include the `%f` directive as well.

Thus: `datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')`